# Integrate Bjam with Eclipse CDT?

Tags: linux, eclipse-cdt, bjam

I have multiple Jamfiles in my source tree.

Some are for building some executables.  Some for static libraries.

By default Eclipse CDT to compile, and I would like to use bjam instead (because other people in the team use bjam and maintain those Jamfiles).

I tried to switch the builder command (in properties->C/C++ build->Builder Settings) to bjam instead of make, and then I updated "Build (incremental build)" (in properties->C/C++ build->Behavior) to call the correct target.

When I hit run, it does call the correct command, but it doesn't see the Jamfile.

Is there a way to specify the jamfile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did that quite easyly by putting a Jamroot into the project folder. I think if you do not want to build all, you would have to specify the target.

Then of course I run b2 in the root directory, not in ./src

Eclipse does provide a custom build enviroment, so maybe there's your issue, so try running b2 from the console.

Comment: Does Eclipse build C++ index correctly for you? Such that it doesn't complain (underlining tons of code in red?)

Comment: Well no, because it does not use the jam files for indexing. You can help that by adding them from hand to the eclipse settings.
There is a plugin for that but I did not get that to work.